# Unable to get Dynatrace Authentication Token via API

Tags: rest, authentication, dynatrace

I am unable to get access token of dynatrace via REST api. I have used the sample REST call provided in the dynatrace documentation but still cannot get the token, but I can log into the account on the portal using these credentials. I have signed up for a free trial account on dynatrace synthetic. Are there any permissions need to be given in order to use APIs.

```
    GET https://datafeed-api.dynatrace.com/publicapi/rest/v1.0/login?
    user=sampleuser&password=samplepw HTTP/1.1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Accept: application/json
    User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
    Host: datafeed-api.dynatrace.com`enter code here`
```

I get "Invalid username or password"

Answer (score 0):

This means either the account has expired or your username + password are incorrect.